# Most efficient: Cut off varchar after first space?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varchar

What is the most efficient way to cut off a varchar after the first space i.e. given `'FIRST_STRING SECOND_STRING THIRD_STRING'`, it should return `'FIRST_STRING'`? This will be run on potentially 100s of thousands of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the `+' '` this will trap any single word

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'FIRST_STRING SECOND_STRING THIRD_STRING'

Select left(@S,charindex(' ',@S+' ')-1)
```

**Returns**

```
FIRST_STRING
```

Comment: I suspect it was a muscle memory thing :)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> declare @str nvarchar(max) = 'FIRST_STRING SECOND_STRING THIRD_STRING';
>
> select left(@str, charindex(' ', @str) - 1)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | FIRST_STRING     |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52a75033740a4f7c53729ecdc349fd1f)*

Comment: You might've beaten @JohnCappelletti if you'd have used '@S' instead of '@str'.